# Chamar Subreport no Relatório principal

Tags: jasper-reports

Galera, tenho 2 relatórios, o sub relatório e o Relatório principal, porém quando dou um preview só consigo visualizar o principal, como faço para exibir o sub relatório também?

Estou usando JasperSoft Studio.

---

Tenho um relatório que é preenchido por uma lista e por parâmetros, porem encontrei um problema e recebi ajuda aqui no fórum, a pessoa que me ajudou disse que a melhor forma de solucionar esse problema seria criando um SubReport.
O problema é o seguinte, eu quero deixar o meu relatório da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver, um Beneficiário tem mais de 1 procedimento. Atualmente eu consigo listar todos os procedimentos e beneficiários, porém os procedimentos se repetem. Isso é o que eu consigo atualmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu o Nome do Beneficiário se repete, e mostra o outro procedimento, não fica tudo junto em apenas um lugar.

Estou tentando colocar um SubReport com o Nome do Beneficiário e Identificador em um Group Header, e os procedimentos (Data Realização, Descrição do Serviço, cod Tab..) dentro do Detail. Acho que dessa forma iria funcionar, porém nao estou conseguindo chamar o SubReport dentro do meu relatório.

Comment: O relatório secundário precisa estar compilado num arquivo `.jasper` em algum diretório específico. E aí no componente do subrelatório no relatório principal você precisa especificar um caminho para o arquivo compilado do subrelatório. Caso precise de mais ajuda, clique em [edit] na sua pergunta e acrescente mais informações sobre o seu relatório. Abraço!

Comment: Entendi, mas como passo esse caminho, qual o tipo do parâmetro?

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/subreports-jaspersoft-studio).

Comment: já olhei porem não entendi, ali ele passa um ID como parametro e suponho que seja por conexão JDBC, utilizando listas como data source funciona da mesma forma?

Comment: Diego Tem como vc me passar o seu relatório para eu usar como modelo ?

Comment: @FillipeDesenvolvedor nossa, não tenho mais acesso a ele faz um tempão hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa especificar o caminho para o subrelatório de dentro do relatório principal.

Isso deve ser feito no componente de subrelatório, em seu atributo `Subreport Expression`, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Definir propriedades do subrelatório]

Aí você pode especificar o caminho para o arquivo `.jasper` do subrelatório através de um dos tipos `String`, `File`, `InputStream`, `URL` e `JaspeReports`.

Comment: Fiz isso mas ainda não carrega o Subreport, tenho que configurar alguma coisa no SubReport?

Comment: Olha como está:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/EZpcV.png

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Não tem erros na aba *Output*?

Comment: Nenhum, acho que não está sendo exibido por retornar tudo nulo, vou tentar chamar por código pelo ImputStream

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Pode ser que não esteja exibindo nada pela falta de dados. Você está passando os parâmetros para o subrelatório? Tente colocar uma query fixa e veja se aparece algo.

Comment: Eu estou tentando passar uma lista, ai que está a dificuldade. Tentei passar o sub report como parametro e deu esse erro: `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
 Source text : $P{sub}`

Comment: @DiegoAugusto Verifique se o tipo de `${sub]` é compatível com o tipo informado no outro campo que informa o tipo. Por exemplo, se for uma String, deve estar `java.lang.String`.

Comment: Estava enviando por InputStream da seguinte forma:
`InputStream sub= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/subRelatorio.jrxml");`

Comment: E depois usava `filtro.put("sub", sub);`

Comment: Mas acho que está dando erro pois estou tentando passar uma lista para o sub relatório e não sei se estou fazendo de forma correta. Resumindo eu preciso passar uma lista para o relatório principal, isso eu já consigo fazer, agora preciso passar uma lista para o sub report e logo em seguida chamar meu Relatório principal com o sub report dentro.